# Saving JSON to text file

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a form. The user adds the title and video URL on a page. This title and URL is read by Javascript and made into JSON. Now my JSON needs to be saved into existing myDB.txt file in JSON format. I'm using Ajax, PHP, and Javascript.  I can't find my error, as JSON is created, I can see it with console log. However, data is not being saved in the text file.

Can someone help me with this task?

```js
function jsonFunc() {
 var nn = document.getElementById('videoName').value;
 var vv = document.getElementById('videoUrl').value;
 var obj = { "name": nn, "url" : vv };
 var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
 console.log(myJSON);
 
 function savePHPfunc(myJSON){
  var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open("GET", "save.php="+myJSON, true);
  x.send();
 }
 
}


 <?php
$myfile = fopen("myDB.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $_GET["myJSON"];
fwrite($myfile, $txt);

fclose($myfile);
?>
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="videoName" id="videoName">Video name
<input type="text" name="videoUrl"  id="videoUrl">Video
<button type="submit" onclick="jsonFunc()">Add video</button>
</form>
```

_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the php is not really commented out, the problem seems to be with the javascript:

```
x.open("GET", "save.php="+myJSON, true);
```

You are not sending the key with the value of your variable. It should be something like:

```
x.open("GET", "save.php?myJSON="+myJSON, true);
```

Note that you should also encode the variable so that it is safe to use as a query variable in your url. You can do that using `encodeURIComponent()`:

```
x.open("GET", "save.php?myJSON="+encodeURIComponent(myJSON), true);
```

Comment: Sir, you wont beleive me, but i made it, yeahh, finally got it onto my fork, for some reason php get method in save php is not writing data onto the text file, i tried php post method, and guess what, i see my json obj inside my database file, i owe u a beer, thanks lot.

Comment: @IlhomJones IMHO you first owe him to accept the answer as correct.

Comment: @IlhomJones You had a typo in your GET variable: it is `$_GET`.

Comment: got another problem in this mini task, yep that typo i saw that earlier, sorry my typo on here, on the actual script dont have that typo,  another problem is after first json obj data written onto db text file, the second one is not being passed in full, i mean the db file is geting the empty line being saved there, the actual user input is not being passed to the db file, am i missing smth here? shall i add some code for closing XML request may be?

Comment: there are two lines on my text file, first line with a comma at the end of json obj was written onto text file successfully, but second line as you can see is empty line created, for some reason php file trying to write the json obj into text file, but unsuccessfully created an empty line, gosh cant find the problem here now,,,,,     here s the exact copy from db text file two lines, first line containt json obj and comma, second line is simply empty         {"name":"test name","url":"uri54r"},

Comment: this works only once and stops, can someone professional help me to find the bug in here?function jsonFunc() {
 var nn = document.getElementById('videoName').value;
 var vv = document.getElementById('videoUrl').value;
 var obj = { "name": nn, "url" : vv };
 var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
 console.log(myJSON);
 
 
 function savePHPfunc(myJSON){
  var xR=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xR.open("POST", "save.php?myJSON=" + myJSON, true);
  xR.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  xR.send();
  console.log(myJSON);
 
 }
 savePHPfunc(myJSON);
}

Comment: @IlhomJones You should post a new question with this specific problem and the relevant code. In the comments it is unreadable.

Comment: i will try to post a new question, however i think people of this community mostly are very untolerant to my questions, to most questions, community in here wants very difficult tasks so they can solve it and enjoy it, well,   by now i have posted three questions in this web site, but I see that community seems very high demanding in here, im getting most times Negatives on mine questions, and people are very aggressive to my questions, to be honest im even a bit scared to create a new question, as i feel i will get all the negativ marks on it, all the masters looking for deep thinking tasks (